# Cylindrical Coordinate System

Tags: coordinate-systems, geometry

I am to write equations of each side for a cylinder.The problem is stated below:

There is a cylinder...One cuts it from somewhere near the center point ( height wise ) . So the cylinder is now split into two semi cylinders. Like cutting a cake . Now put another cut on any side of the 2 semi cylinders in a way that an almost rectangular front face is obtained.

The shape obtained now is almost 3D rectangle which is a perfect rectangle in  2 dimensions and the 3rd side is a little curved ( as the cylinder was curved )

I need to write equations for all its dimensions. Please help.

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?

Comment: I will add a tag, I am almost nill at this thing :(

Comment: What do you mean by "write equations for all its dimensions"? Something like $x=\sqrt{5-y^2}$, etc.  You should spend some time staring and thinking about circles stacked on top of each other.  Get a piece of clay and make a cylinder, etc.  You won't learn to think if we tell you an answer.